# Why can't I create my own custom component in Google Chrome 48?

Tags: google-chrome, polymer-1.0, web-component

I have built a library of custom elements using the webcomponents polyfills provided by Polymer. It works in Firefox and Safari. But it doesn't work in Chrome 48 with native component support. I can make it work if I use the polyfill code hacked to not use the native implementation...

Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    var myComp = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
    document.registerElement('my-comp', {prototype: myComp}); 
    myComp.attachedCallback = function () {
      console.log('my-comp attached');
    }
  </script>

</head>
  <body>
   <my-comp></my-comp>
   <p> Just to check that page is loaded</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I should see the message in the console, but nothing is displayed. Support is enabled in Chrome (I can see that `document.registerElement` is native), my code is loaded and executed (the element is registered, I get a warning if I try to register it again in the console), and the callback is valid (I can call it by hand in the console).

What happens? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will make it work by attaching event handlers **before** registering element:

```
var myComp = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
myComp.attachedCallback = function () 
{
  console.log('my-comp attached');
}
document.registerElement('my-comp', {prototype: myComp});
```

Comment: I feel stupid, it works that way... I should have tried that. Thank you!

Comment: You should not. Its ok to miss such things if it happens not often:)